# IntelliJ - can't load FormPreviewFrame.class in the GUI Designer

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to Intellij IDEA (community edition 2020.1), I wanted to try a simple JSwing Form. The form is displayed well at runtime but the problem is with the GUI Editor/Designer, if I try to preview the form, it says, "can't load FormPreviewFrame.class"

I also have a secondary supplementary question, I see that a default JPanel is created in the GUI Designer, is this the default content pane of the JFrame created? I mean do I need to add that JPanel to the JFrame? (though it worked without the addition)

UPDATE EDITED: I think this is a old bug which has not been fixed yet, as stated [HERE](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237293?_ga=2.190402411.1747303611.1589222834-106971910.1588423721) and [HERE](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206357719-977-Preview-still-doesn-t-work-)

[image]

The following is my simple JFrame, I bound the "MyMainForm" class to the UI Form (.form)

```
class MyMainForm extends JFrame{
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel lbl;
    private JButton btn;

    public MyMainForm(String title) throws HeadlessException {
        super(title);
        //setSize( 150, 100 );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        this.panel = new JPanel();
        this.lbl = new JLabel("Result");
        this.btn = new JButton("Calculate");

        panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setBounds(400,200,500,500);

        add(lbl);
        add(btn);
        this.pack();

    }
}

public class MyFrameTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyMainForm frm= new MyMainForm("Calculator");
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u but the class runs well, the problem is ONLY with the UI Designer. The Preview doesnt work

Comment: I think this is a BUG as stated here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206357719-977-Preview-still-doesn-t-work-
and here  https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206357719-977-Preview-still-doesn-t-work-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237293). The fix will be available in 2020.1.2 update.

Comment: yup I just found it and updated my question as well. Thank u